# How did Swami Dayananda Saraswati get the title of 'Maharshi'?

Tags: dayananda-saraswati

The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayananda_Saraswati) and many institutions refer to him as 'Maharshi Dayananda Saraswati'. What is the story behind him getting the title?